# how to pick up date time range for every Monday in specific range of date

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to get date time range for every Monday in specific period and i am able to do this from this month to end of year but i am stack to set period dynamically.

```
This is my code 

enum DAYS {
    MON = 1,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN
}

function getDays(day) {
    const d = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        days = [];
    d.setDate(day);
    while (d.getDay() !== day) {
        console.log('d')
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }

    while (d.getMonth()) {
        const date = new Date(d.getTime())
        const start = date.getTime()
        const end = start + 24 * 60 * 60
        const range = {
            date,
            start,
            end
        }
        days.push(range);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return days;
}

const Mondays = getDays(DAYS.MON)
const Tuesdays = getDays(DAYS.TUE)
console.log(Mondays)
console.log(Tuesdays)
```

for example if i want to have all Monday from 14/06/2019 to 13/06/2020 how i can set period as start date and end date?
Could you please someone advice me?

Comment: *enum* is a future [reserved word](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ReservedWord), which implementation is using it?

Comment: `while (d.getMonth())` will stop at January when *getMonth* returns 0. What you need is to create a date for the end of the range, say called *endDate*, and do `while (d < endDate)`.

Comment: Hi RobG thanks for your tips.

as you said i replaced d.getMonth() to endDate and success to implement this.

Thank you.

ive attached the code for the future questioner !

Answer (score 0):

```
    enum DAYS {
    MON = 1,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN
}

function getDays(day, startDate, endDate) {
    const d = new Date(startDate)
    const days = [];
    d.setDate(day);
    while (d.getDay() !== day) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }
    while (d < endDate) {
        if (d >= startDate) {
            const date = new Date(d.getTime())
            const start = date.getTime()
            const end = start + 24 * 60 * 60
            const range = {
                date,
                start,
                end
            }
            days.push(range);
        }
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return days;
}

const startDate = new Date('Thu Jan 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)')
const endDate = new Date('Thu Jun 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)')
const day = DAYS.MON
const Mondays = getDays(day, startDate, endDate)
```